# How to copy values from safearray to vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, safearray

I have a call returning safearray of BSTR. I want to copy it to a `vector<LPOLESTR>`. What is the correct way to do it? How is the memory handled in this case?

Comment: How do you plan to allocate and manage memory that those pointers in the vector are all pointing to? Recall that the safearray owns its `BSTR`s and will deallocate them when it itself is destroyed. You might be happier with `vector<wstring>`, or perhaps `vector<CString>` if you are into MFC or ATL.

Comment: I was thinking on similar lines. Finally decided to go with vector<wstring>. Any algorithm to copy the contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want `vector<wstring>` after all, per discussion in comments, something like this:

```
SAFEARRAY* sa;  // a safearray of BSTR, initialized somehow.

LONG lBound, uBound;
SafeArrayGetLBound(sa, 1, &lBound);
SafeArrayGetUBound(sa, 1, &uBound);
LONG count = uBound - lBound + 1;  // bounds are inclusive

BSTR* raw;
SafeArrayAccessData(sa, (void**)&raw);

vector<wstring> v(raw, raw + count);
// or, if you want to assign to an existing vector
vector<wstring> v;
v.assign(raw, raw + count);

// When no longer need "raw".
SafeArrayUnaccessData(sa);
```

Error handling is left as an exercise for the reader.